# Am planning to upgrade angular v1.2.17 to latest legacy version 1.2.29

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Will there be any changes required in the code for this minor version upgrade ?

Comment: I guess there will be changes, you've to check the ChangeLog of the AngularJS

Comment: Thanks @Tushar it helps a lot. But i guess, there should not be any ground breaking change in minor version release. They often involve performance and bug fixes only.. Right ?

Comment: Angular Team has also added Breaking change list in the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that directly in the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)